# Python - Read table

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

In python using the lxml library how do i read an html tables td values? I tried reading the xpath table but i cant find the right parameter to returns the td values. Thanks everyone, i appreciate it.

```
import sys
from glob import *
from lxml import etree, html
import requests
#Scan directory (current) and scrape the html files
dirScan = glob('html/*.*')
fileCount = 0
while(fileCount < len(dirScan)):
    fileName =  dirScan[fileCount]
    page = open(fileName)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.read())
   tables = tree.xpath('//table')
   print("Tables:",tables)
```

page.html

```
 <table style="width:100%">
 <tr align="right"><td>1</td><td>John</td><td>Smith</td>
 <tr align="right"><td>2</td><td>Tody</td><td>Miller</td>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you know how to use an xpath?

Comment: Not really, and i cant find any good documentation on it. Im tyring to grab all the td values that are after the tr align="right",but i cant get the syntax right.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp `xpath("//table/tr[@align='right']/td")`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks. How do i convert it to string values. It shows up as a list of Elements like so.....=>
[0]:<Element td at 0x7fee11ab2958>
[1]:<Element td at 0x7fee11ac68b8>
[2]:<Element td at 0x7fee11ac6908>
[3]:<Element td at 0x7fee11ac6958>

Comment: Just use`xpath("//table/tr[@align='right']/td/text()")` to extract the text

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Please commit this answer so i can give you points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find the *td's* inside the *tr's* with align right, you need ti filter using the align attribute:

```
tds = tree.xpath("//table/tr[@align='right']/td")
```

If you just want the text from each td:

```
.xpath("//table/tr[@align='right']/td/text()")
```

But really you probably want to keep the association so you should just find the trs, then group the td text:

```
x = """<table style="width:100%">
 <tr align="right"><td>1</td><td>John</td><td>Smith</td>
 <tr align="right"><td>2</td><td>Tody</td><td>Miller</td>
</table> """

from lxml import html

tree = html.fromstring(x)

# first get the trs, filtering by attribute 
trs = tree.xpath("//table/tr[@align='right']")

# then extract the tds from each tr 
data = [row.xpath("td/text()") for row in trs]
```

Which would give you:

```
[['1', 'John', 'Smith'], ['2', 'Tody', 'Miller']]
```

And if you just wanted each name, you could skip the first td:

```
trs = tree.xpath("//table/tr[@align='right']")

# position() > 1, all but the first td, xpath has one based indexing.
names = [row.xpath("td[position()> 1]/text()") for row in trs])
```

Or join into a single string:

```
 full_names [" ".join(row.xpath("td[position()> 1]/text()")) for row in trs]
```

Comment: Are you kidding me you changed the answer based on his comment 

Comment: @HishamKaram, I changed what answer? Also the correct way to just get text from td's is not to `//text()`, it would pull text recursively and as pointed out in my answer it would lose any association by just pulling all the text into one flat list.

Comment: i mean he changed the answer and edited the question from 2 hours only is that fair enough ?

Comment: @HishamKaram, ignoring any edit, `//text()` is wrong and even `tree.xpath('//tr/td/text()')` as I already commented gives you a list of strings that hold no association.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Is there a way where i can grab like the first 10 elements of the td list, or do i have to go through all the items?

Comment: @John, it returns a list so a simple slice would work, or using position like I used above, position() < 11:

Answer (score 0):

code

```
 >>> page="""<table style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Miller</td>
        <td>43</td>
      </tr>
    </table> """
    >>> tree=html.fromstring(s)
    >>> tree.xpath('//tr/td//text()')
```

output:

```
['1', 'Smith', '50', '2', 'Jackson', '94', '3', 'Miller', '43']
```

Comment: Hey my list has a lot of \n and other junk. Is it because the table im scrape has style attributes.

Comment: What would be the syntax to read all the tr align="right" values ?